# How can I create my own file type on Node?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron, mime-types, file-type

I am wondering if I can change the mime-type of a file on Node. I have checked many mime-type modules, but all of them are just to get information from the files and from the system.

What I would like to achieve is to zip some files in one single file and then, change the mime-type. On this way I could check if the file type is suited for my application.

I know there are differences between operating systems:

- Windows. I change the extension and it is done
- Ubuntu. I must deal with mime-types. This is what I would like to change
- Mac. They have a system similar to Ubuntu.

How to achieve this on Ubuntu or Mac?

Assuming that I can do it and I have just changed the mime-type of a zip file on Ubuntu, is it still going to detect the file as a zip file by the system?

If all of this is not possible. How can I create my own file built with different files?

For example I would like to include all these files compressed inside the packaged file called `filename.foo`:

- An XML file with metadata
- A text file
- A CSV file
- An image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have changed the file extension and added a new MIME-TYPE to the system. In this way Nautilus (Ubuntu) and the Windows explorer recognise the file with the new type.

When I use the command `file --mime-type` I still detect the zip mime-type. But that's not bad because I can use this detection to avoid errors in my app.

#### Create your own MIME-TYPE for Nautilus

1. Create a new XML in `/usr/share/mime/packages/` with this content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
     <mime-type type="application/todo">
       <comment>Todos Text file</comment>
       <glob pattern="*.TODO"/>
       <glob pattern="*.todo"/>
     </mime-type>
   </mime-info>
   ```
2. Execute the following command to update mime database

   ```
   sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
   ```

#### Assign an icon to the new extension

First step is renaming the icon to application-todo and it must be in svg extension.

If you're using gnome you have move the icon to `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable` then update the cache with

```
$ sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/gnome -f
```

If you're using unity move it to `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/` then update the cache

```
$ sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/Humanity -f
```

Give your nautilus a refresh and you'll have a new mime-type with icon

Answer (score -2):

Most higher level applications make use of the file extension to determine an approprite mime type.

OS X, Linux and UNIX systems can make use of the 'file' command which uses a pre compiled database of header and the offset at which the unique identifier for the mime type exists; see /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc

While I can only think of one reason to modify a created archive to a different mime type which is undoubtedly nefarious it is possible would require hex editing the archive to create/pretend the associated signature at the correct offset.

Of course this would then require your node module to first strip this unnecessary header prior to extraction.

Comment: So how would you create your own file with its filetype? I would like to package some files to one in order to open them on my application

Comment: I added an example to my question

Comment: Strange, my answer indicates how this would be accomplished already. What part is confusing?

Comment: So I had to strip the header of the file, how? Can I add the new header with the command `file`? Is there another way to create my own filetype from scratch? instead of changing the mime type

Comment: Your original post indicated you wished to change the current mime type of an archive, compressed or otherwise to another mime type. My assumption is that you wished to use an existing mime type which would require the addition of specific header values to exist at specific addresses within the file. Now you seem to want to create a new mime type altogether. If the later is the case then you can easily use the aforementioned manual to do so.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to create my own file type changing the file type of a file already created. But maybe there is a better way to do that if I start from scratch. Could you give me a hint if you know how to do it? Thanks